# Analysing the edges between two vertices gremlin

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Here is my graph

```
g.addV('user').property('id',1).as('1').
  addV('user').property('id',2).as('2').
  addV('user').property('id',3).as('3').
  addE('follow').from('1').to('2').
  addE('follow').from('1').to('3').iterate()
```

The below is my approach when a user wants to follow another user suppose 2 wants to follow 3

I'm checking first whether follow edge exist between 2 and 3

```
if(g.V().has(id, 2).outE(follow).inV().has(id, 3).hasNext())
 {
   //if exists that means he already following him so i'm dropping the follow edge and adding unfollow edge to 2,3.
 }
 else if(g.V().has(id, 2).outE(unfollow).inV().has(id, 3).hasNext())
 {
   //if exists he already unfollowed him and he wants to follow him again i'm dropping the unfollow edge and adding the follow edge to 2,3.
 }
 else 
 {
   // there is no edges between 2,3 so he is following him first so i'm adding follow edge 2,3.
 }
```

but the drawback of this approach is every time it needs to query 2 times which impacts performance . Can you suggest me a better approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build if-then-else semantics with `choose()`. A direct translation of your logic there would probably look like this:

```
gremlin> g.addV('user').property(id,1).as('1').
......1>   addV('user').property(id,2).as('2').
......2>   addV('user').property(id,3).as('3').
......3>   addE('follow').from('1').to('2').
......4>   addE('follow').from('1').to('3').iterate()
gremlin> g.V(3).as('target').
......1>   V(2).as('source').
......2>   choose(outE('follow').aggregate('d1').inV().hasId(3), 
......3>            sideEffect(addE('unfollow').from('source').to('target').
......4>                       select('d1').unfold().drop()).constant('unfollowed'),
......5>          choose(outE('unfollow').aggregate('d2').inV().hasId(3),
......6>                   sideEffect(addE('follow').from('source').to('target').
......7>                              select('d2').unfold().drop()).constant('followed'),
......8>                 addE('follow').from('source').to('target').constant('followed-first')))
==>followed-first
gremlin> g.E()
==>e[0][1-follow->2]
==>e[1][1-follow->3]
==>e[2][2-follow->3]
gremlin> g.V(3).as('target').
......1>   V(2).as('source').
......2>   choose(outE('follow').aggregate('d1').inV().hasId(3), 
......3>            sideEffect(addE('unfollow').from('source').to('target').
......4>                       select('d1').unfold().drop()).constant('unfollowed'),
......5>          choose(outE('unfollow').aggregate('d2').inV().hasId(3),
......6>                   sideEffect(addE('follow').from('source').to('target').
......7>                              select('d2').unfold().drop()).constant('followed'),
......8>                 addE('follow').from('source').to('target').constant('followed-first')))
==>unfollowed
gremlin> g.E()
==>e[0][1-follow->2]
==>e[1][1-follow->3]
==>e[3][2-unfollow->3]
gremlin> g.V(3).as('target').
......1>   V(2).as('source').
......2>   choose(outE('follow').aggregate('d1').inV().hasId(3), 
......3>            sideEffect(addE('unfollow').from('source').to('target').
......4>                       select('d1').unfold().drop()).constant('unfollowed'),
......5>          choose(outE('unfollow').aggregate('d2').inV().hasId(3),
......6>                   sideEffect(addE('follow').from('source').to('target').
......7>                              select('d2').unfold().drop()).constant('followed'),
......8>                 addE('follow').from('source').to('target').constant('followed-first')))
==>followed
gremlin> g.E()
==>e[0][1-follow->2]
==>e[1][1-follow->3]
==>e[4][2-follow->3]
```

Comment: i mean....your proposed logic contains no less than 5 separate traversals. my answer combines those 5 separate requests into one request to neptune. i suppose it might be possible to improve a bit more by traversing `outE()` only once and after trying that for a bit I found it less readable and I wasn't sure how neptune would optimize that - there may be negligible difference so without being able to test i thought the optimization was premature. Anyway, there may be other ways to tackle this one, but this direct approach seemed like the best place to start given that 5 requests turned to 1

Comment: You can add a `constant('follow')` or something to the ends of the mutation/sideEffect steps so that you know which one executed and it will return in the output. not sure why you're getting that error - you probably just have a parenthesis out of place. check your arguments against the javadoc: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html (i tested the traversal so it should work)

Comment: i included my entire console session

Comment: hmm - i'm not sure what would get things into that state. i'm unable to recreate this in TinkerGraph - is this happening in neptune? are you submitting these requests in fast succession (perhaps the requests are interfering with one another)? to debug, i would look carefully at what the state of the edges are between each request.

Comment: I tried the steps that Stephen showed above using Neptune and got the same results as Stephen. If you need immediate consistency you may want to be issuing these calls against the Neptune cluster endpoint (write master). If you are issuing the requests against a read replica there is a chance of a small latency before the readers catch up with the write master. Are you using any read replicas? If your queries depend upon immediate consistency then perhaps issue them against the write master. That will get you ACID/Immediate Consistency.

Comment: Are your queries the same as Stephen's or different? Obviously any writes such as an addE would need to be sent to the write master (cluster) endpoint but if you are doing pure reads from a read replica shortly after doing writes there is a chance that the read replica is behind (by a few milliseconds only not by a large amount)